# Static Images not Loading on Django Project

Tags: python, django, templates, configuration, static

I just had to restart my app from scratch (at least from setup point of view) due to a migration issue which seemed to mess up my whole db.

Anyway, my problem now is with my `img` and `css` directories not loading at all.

I've verified the `urls.py` is working fine, as I can access urls specified in there, but no images, css, etc. are showing up.

**In settings.py I have:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/c0de/appWs/git/djangoapp/MyApp/MyApp/Scanner/static/'
PROJECT_ROOT_LOCAL = "/Users/c0de/MyAppWs/git/djangoapp/MyApp/MyApp/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_LOCAL, 'Scanner/templates/'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #django-default apps
    'MyApp',
)
```

In my templates, I'm doing calls like:

```
 <img src="{% static "img/templated/home/img.png" %}" width="85" height="85" alt="img" />
```

`templates` and `static` dir are at this path:

```
/Users/c0de/appWs/git/djangoapp/MyApp/MyApp/Scanner/templates/
/Users/c0de/appWs/git/djangoapp/MyApp/MyApp/Scanner/static/
```

I've also tried restarting my local default-django server.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The reason could be you might have ran `collectstatic` command and put DEBUG=False in your settings file.try changing DEBUG=True and see.

Comment: DEBUG=True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG=DEBUG are already in place @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy

Comment: I am not sure of the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly, silly me.

All this time I thought it was an issue with the paths of `STATIC_ROOT` or `TEMPLATE_DIRS` or `STATIC_URL`

It came down to loading not the application, but the project in `INSTALLED_APPS`. It still seems strange it would show the whole application, but not the `img` or `css` files, but still lload the template.

Now that the actual `application` is set in `INSTALLED_APPS()` and not the `project` (containing this application) this seems to be working fine.